# Select the MYSQL5.7 series that matches the condition from the result of the SELECT clause

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum, subquery

#### what I want to do

In MYSQL5.7 series, I want to SELECT the items that meet the conditions from the result of the SELECT clause, but I can not select.

#### The code I created

```sql
select
   b_id
   , created_at
   , (select count(*)+1 
     from a
     where b_id = x.b_id and created_at > x.created_at
  ) as n
from a as x
order by x.b_id, x.created_at desc
;
```

#### results of this code

Running the above code produces the following result. I would like to modify the above code to count the number n=1 for the following result, but I am not sure how.

```
b_id        created_at            n
1           20/07/18 22:47  1   
2           20/03/24 06:08  1       
5           20/08/30 19:25  1   
6           20/08/29 14:53  2   
6           20/08/27 00:00  3
```

#### What I tried

I thought it would be possible to get it by enclosing the select clause in a subquery as follows and counting the select results with a condition, but I could not.

```sql
select
  count(y.n = 1)
from(
  select
   b_id
   , created_at
   , (select count(*)+1 
     from a
     where b_id = x.b_id and created_at > x.created_at
   ) as n
  from a as x
  order by x.b_id, x.created_at desc
) as y;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

The immediate issue with expression `count(y.n = 1)`. The condition returns either `0` or `1`, which both are counted - `count()` ignores `null` values only. You can use `sum(y.n - 1)` instead.

I am unsure about the purpose of the query. Basically this ranks records having the same `b_id` by descending date - then you want to count how many records are ranked first? That's equivalent to just counting how many distinct `b_id`s exist in the table. If so, you could simply phrase it as:

```
select count(distinct b_id) 
from a
```